# html file download on node server

Tags: html

Within my public folder on my node.js server I have a standard html website set up.
Im trying to download files from a webpage using

```
<a href="../Files/" download="Solar.zip">Download</a>
```

but i keep getting:
[image: error on download]
my folder structure looks like this(shortened)
Files
 -Solar.zip
public
 -project.html
Where project.html is where I have the button to download.Should i be using a get instead? or is it not html related at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add full path to `zip` file in `href` attribute:

```
<a href="../Files/Solar.zip" download="Solar.zip">Download</a>
```

[`download`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download) attribute just allows you to set a separate file download name than the actual link. For example:

```
<a href="../Files/a.zip" download="b.zip">Download</a>
```

will start downloading file `a.zip` but will rename it to `b.zip`